# Hide image on homepage

Tags: css

I want hide images on excerpts only on the homepage of my blog and only when the screen resolution is under 480px. Is it possible to do this ?

I know I can set an CSS propriety for the width but I don't know how to specifiy only for me homepage, maybe with a function ?

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: The answer is going to be site/theme-specific. Can you provide a link to your site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the default WordPress `.home` class(it is a part of the `body_class()` function that is added by default to every `body` html tag):

```
@media screen and (max-width : 320px) { 
    .home .your-featured-image {
        display: none;
     }
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/

Answer (score 0):

You must inspect whether at the `<body>` of the homepage page there is a `home` class. If yes, just add this code to style.css

```
@media screen and (max-width : 320px) { 
    .home .your-image {
        display: none;
     }
}
```

if no, you must edit your `<body>` tag it's usually in the `header.php` of your theme.
Replace `<body>` with `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>` , but if you see the `<body>` tag has an additional class like `<body class="something-class">` replace the body tag with this code `<body <?php body_class( 'something-class' ); ?>>`